# Fetch Facebook Friend Id in Android on Invite send to the user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is fetching the facebook friend's id in android.I have integrated my app to send the invites to the user.But I need to fetch the friend id to whom the invite has been send.Is there any way can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Facebook App Invite

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites

or

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

Comment: I am able to send the invite.But I need to fetch the friend id to whom the invite has been send.Please can you provide me the solution

Comment: You cant get that type of information from facebook.

Comment: I want to fetch that information in the App to keep track of successful invites

Comment: That Type of information is not available form the facebook sdk till now .

Comment: There should be some way.It was possible with the earlier version of facebook sdk.

Comment: yeah in older version this feature is available , but now its not available in app invite , I think you can achieve this using Game invite from Facebook

Comment: I know this stuff sir but my app is not the gaming app.

Comment: yeah their are some restrictions on facebook sdk now. So no other way to do this